# Django model is inheriting all super model Fields, except for IntegerField

Tags: django, django-models, django-inheritance

I'm having a weird issue, I have a models' hierarchy, an abstract User class:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    access_token = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True)
    notifications_token = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True)
    person_in_contact = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    confirmedEmail = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    confirmedPhone = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    completedProfile = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return "Client : " + self.user_name + " Email:" + self.email

    def get_email(self):
        return self.email

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user_name'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_name', 'phone', 'password']

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

then a person class and a company (no issue with this one) class that inherit from this one:

```
class Person(User):
    GENDER = (('F', 'FEMALE'), ('M', 'MALE'))

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER, null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def age(self):
        today = date.today()
        return today.year - self.birth_date.year

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return super().__str__() + " Name : " + self.name

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

as you can see, the only field that's IntegerField() is the age field.
now i have a Traveller and a Driver classes that inherit from the person class,
the issue is the age field, doesn't show in the database, unless i override it in  one of the classes, that's what i did, i override it in traveller so it appeared in the database, but didn't override it in the driver, so it didn't show.
Traveller:

```
class Traveller(Person):
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='travellers/profile_pictures')
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Travellers'
```

Driver:

```
class Driver(Person):
    rating = models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=1, max_digits=3)
    driving_license = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    insurance_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(TransportCompany, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='drivers/profile_pictures')
```

i need to know how i can fix this, or what's the issue, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You did *nod* add an `age` field here. Since you defined a function with the same name, that attribute is "overwritten". Please rename one of the two.

Comment: Note that the age is furthermore *not* the difference between the year of dob and the current year.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks dude, I fixed the mthod name, and it solved the issue, but i didn't get what you mean by "the age is not the difference between the year of dob and the current year"... how is it calculated then?

Comment: why are you storing the age in the database in the first place if you have the dob? Never store properties that can be calculated from other fields. If I were you, I'd remove the `age` field entirely and just keep the `def age(self)` method (change it to a `@property`, even better) to return the calculated value.

Comment: @wassimchaguetmi: if your birthday is december 1, 2000; then then right now you are 18 years old, not 19, since you did not have your birthday this year.

Comment: @dirkgoten: I think because a person might decide to specify his/her age, not his/her dob.

Comment: yeah you're right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is because your `age` field has the same name as the `age` function. As a result, the `age = ...` field is ignored by Python in favor of the `age` function, since that is the last time you defined the `age` variable.

For the same reason the `age` field pops up in sublasses: you defined an `age` variable over there, and that takes precedence over the "inherited" age method.

You should rename one of the two. For example with:

```
class Person(User):
    GENDER = (('F', 'FEMALE'), ('M', 'MALE'))

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER, null=True)
    _age = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def age(self):
        today = date.today()
        bod = self.birth_date
        before_dob = (today.month, today.day) < (bod.month, bod.day)
        return today.year - self.birth_date.year - before_dob

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Note that the calculation of the `age` was not completely accurate: if we are before the birthday of that year, you need to subtract one from the age.